# CocoaPods: pod install gives "Errno::E2BIG - Arg list too long"

Tags: ios, bash, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

I am developing with flutter and need to add some Firebase SDKs to the iOS project. I was able to get CocoaPods to generate the Podfile, shown below, but got the following error on pod install (I resolved the second warning):

[image]

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

EDIT:

The folder containing bash.exe was not on the PATH, and I this is my new issue:

```
Errno::E2BIG - Arg list too long - C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213:in `popen_run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:101:in `popen3'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:175:in `popen3'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:67:in `execute_command'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:27:in `block in executable'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in run_prepare_command'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb:60:in `chdir'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb:60:in `block in run_prepare_command'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb:59:in `run_prepare_command'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb:37:in `prepare!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:202:in `copy_and_clean'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in uncached_pod'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:157:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:157:in `block in uncached_pod'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `in_tmpdir'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `uncached_pod'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:69:in `install!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:557:in `install_source_of_pod'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:508:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:507:in `block in install_pod_sources'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `install_pod_sources'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:248:in `block in download_dependencies'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:247:in `download_dependencies'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:157:in `install!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/pod:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1036#issuecomment-20675439 to add UTF-8.

Comment: Ops! I dont even this working on windows. Pods working but IOS stuff?

Comment: I don't see why it would need to be MacOS to install some dependencies

Comment: Why do you need to install packages for IOS, in windows? I think it is pointless

Comment: I don't have a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in terminal to resolve issue.

```
echo "export LANG=en_us.utf-8" >> ~/.profile
```

That looks like exactly what the error is telling you to do.

Comment: This is a non fatal warning unrelated to the issue at hand, however I did the following and the warning disappeared, so thanks. Just need to figure out the real issue now.

Comment: Is bash.exe on your system?